# lxml bug in .xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

After going through the xpath in lxml tutorial for python I'm finding it hard to understand 2 behaviors that seem like bugs to me. Firstly, lxml seems to return a list even when my xpath expression clearly selects only one element, and secondly .xpath seems to return the elements' parent rather than the elements themselves selected by a straight forward xpath search expression.

Is my understanding of XPath all wrong or does lxml indeed have a bug?

The script to replicate the behaviors I'm talking about:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
doc = fromstring("""
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>Paragraph 1</p>
            <p>Paragraph 2</p>
        </body>
    </html>
""")

print doc.xpath("//html")
#[<Element html at 1f385e0>]
#(This makes sense - return a list of all possible matches for html)

print doc.xpath("//html[1]")
#[<Element html at 1f385e0>]
#(This doesn't make sense - why do I get a list when there
#can clearly only be 1 element returned?)   

print doc.xpath("body")
#[<Element body at 1d003e8>]
#(This doesn't make sense - according to
#http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp if I use a tag name
#without any leading / I should get the *child* nodes of the named
#node, which in this case would mean I get a list of
#p tags [<Element p at ...>, <Element p at ...>]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because the context node of `doc` is `'html'` node. When you use `doc.xpath('body')` it select the child element `'body'` of `'html'`. This conforms [XPath 1.0 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `doc.xpath()` always returns a list as it should. It simplifies the code that uses `.xpath()`. It is a good idea in general to always return objects that confirm to the same protocol (in this case a sequence of elements).

Answer (score 0):

All p tags should be `doc.findall(".//p")`

As per guide, expression `nodename` *Selects all child nodes **of the named node***.
Thus, to use only nodename (without trailing /), you must have a named node selected (to select parent node as named node, use dot).

Comment: My problem is not that I can't figure out how to use lxml to select all p tags. My problem is finding out why exactly lxml doesn't have a bug because it is behaving differently to what I'd expect based on the XPath tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In fact `doc.xpath("//html[1]")` can return more than one node with a different input document from your example. That path picks the first sibling that matches //html. If there are matching non sibling elements, it will select the first  sibling of each of them.
 XPath: `(//html)[1]` forces a different order of evaluation. It selects all of the matching elements in the document and then chooses the first.

But, in any case, it's a better API design to always return a list. Otherwise, code would always have to test for single or None values before processing the list.